# Passing data and event between Content, Background and Script/popup for chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have read the documentation for Message passing between scripts but still not sure how and when to use which method.

Some suggest using

```
* chrome.runtime.sendMessage({...})
* chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(...)
* chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { greeting: 'hello' })
```

I am really confused between these.

My use case is something like pass message from background to content and then content to background to popup script and so on.

Can someone please explain how to pass data between `Content, Background and popup script`?

It would be great if you help me with some kind of example.

Comment: See the official [demo extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples).

Comment: Thanks but didn't found anything relevant showing use of all `background/content and popup js` script.

Comment: Well, it's not clear what exactly needs clarification. The documentation is pretty straightforward. There are many existing answers too. Depending on the specifics, there can be multiple ways to organize messaging...

Comment: Like wOxxOm said, [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) is pretty straightforward. You can update the question for any specific problems you are having.

Comment: okay @PredatorIWD I'll update my question soon with some piece of code and problem, Thanks woxxom too.